# How to structure the code of a python data pre-processing pipeline (for production)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset with a defined structure of columns for which I have built a script/pipeline that generally does: **first**, ingests the data (formatting, cleaning, etc.), and **second**, it transform values and creates a new column with these new transformed values (final result), more or less like this:

1. Imports csv into pandas framework, fills nans, cleans some values in some columns, homogenizes text, names, etc.
   1.1. Creates a new column (cleaned names)
2. Transform/convert values in another column via look ups in dictionaries, doing groupbys, etc. 
   2.2 Creates 1 new column (transformed values)

My script is divided into two files (~150 lines of code, each) and is composed of many methods: `.where, .replace, .map, .apply, .etc`. Given that pandas allows for method chaining and is very flexible, the dataset can be processed without defining any function (except a few for ) `df.apply(func)`. My code gets the csv into a df and naturally starts processing it with the mentioned methods `.where, .replace, .map, .apply, .etc` without using any function or a `.pipeline` method. My project tree looks like:

```
/project
    table.csv
    ingest.py (outputs a clean intermediate_table.csv)
    transform.py (reads previous table.csv and outputs a final_table.csv)
    final_table.csv
```

The thing is, I need to send this code over to other people who will run my script in more datasets, so I will need to comment and **test** it. Given the above, here are my questions in terms of the code structure.

- Should I have a function for each of the steps above?
- If so, with what granularity?

E.g. Should I have multiple functions like below?:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

def uppercase_column_A(dataframe, col) 
def clean_column(dataframe, col) 
def calculate_mean_here(dataframe, col)
def transform_values_there(dataframe, col)

df
.pipe(uppercase_column_A)
.pipe(clean_column)
.pipe(calculate_mean_here)
.pipe(transform_values_there)
.pipe(etc)
)
```

or, maybe, just two big functions ?

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
def ingest(df): returns intermediate_df
def transform(intermediate_df)

df
.pipe(ingest)
.pipe(transform)
```

- Do I actually need to use .pipe? at all
- Should I use classes? separate into modules?

I know the question is broad but I think common practices are important as well as the code itself. In academia (my background), this does not matter much as there is not a 'production' side. So, in general, what would be a recommended industry-way of building data pipelines in terms of code/structure?

Comment: what's the level of Python understanding the other users will have? Your answer will inform a lot about how you want to structure your code :)

Comment: I think having many small functions, which users need to know to call is more confusing, and difficult. How would they know to call all of those functions in the Transform step? Also order can be important, and you can't enforce it with separate functions. Further, you don't gain much having a function like `uppecase_column_A` that likely is just a rename of something like `df.column_A.str.upper`?

Comment: @zero, I don't know that but I am trying to keep on the safe side. Maybe not do something perfect and shiny, but if I can avoid newbies mistakes/practices and do a decent structure, that'd be awesome. Thanks

Comment: My suggestion, would be to have a `def transform(df, **kwargs)` where there are many arguments that allow you to selectively call any of the transformations you want. For instance, the defaults may all be None, so that `transform` simply passes the `DataFrame`, or if a user passes stuff like `upper_cols=['ColA', 'ColB',]` it would transform those columns to uppercase. This ensures that the ordering of transformations is preserved, which can be important.

Comment: @ALollz. If I wrote a function uppecase_column_A() is to exemplify that it's possible to encapsulate the most trivial thing. That helps my question: What granularity should I use for my functions? If you recommend to use them for a pipeline...

Comment: It's hard to say. General guidelines are that a function should serve a single, fairly specific purpose. I generally found that the lines are easiest to find when writing unit tests. If I was trying to test something (say typecasting of variables) and found I needed to worry about other unrelated inputs (like making strings uppercase), it was clear that I made a mistake and needed to refactor something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, using smaller functions is better for maintenance since error codes will be easier to follow the fewer level of abstractions there are (which is what having 2 big functions will *not* do).

My personal suggestion:

1. Add as many comments as you can. Above functions, above variable names, below a function call, etc...
2. Be as descriptive about naming structure. `calculate_mean_of_columns` instead of `calc_mean_cols`, for example. Avoid, as much as you can, using abbreviations (even standard abbreviations in the DS community) like `df` or `cols`.
3. I'd structure my folders differently, honestly. My typical pipelines have had a consistent structure like this:

   ```
   /project
       /code
            code_to_transform_dataframe.py
       /data
            datetimestamp_filename.csv
       /output
            datetimestamp_output.csv
   ```

You can use this as a framework for your own use case but that's for the work I've done in a couple of different companies.

Comment: Two questions:
Do you uses df.pipe to chain all your functions?
Did you feel the need to separate your code into modules, use classes? or just a single file with many functions works fine.

Comment: @Kaisar I use separate modules  but that defeats the purpose of "fewer level of abstractions". separate modules scales up easier and better (say you need to insert a new transformation between 2 actions in your ETL pipeline). In your case, I'd use just 1 module as a `helper_function.py` then import it into the main Python file used for ETL, like say `etl.py` will contain a `from helper_function import *` so all the functions get imported. Avoid classes. Classes in Python are tricky for people not experienced with OOP.

Comment: Also, as I mentioned: I try to be as descriptive. I avoid using `.pipe`. Instead, I use multiple lines like `df = transform_this(df)` or `df = df.apply(transform_this)`

Comment: I am not sure if what I am doing is ETL, by only transforming/cleaning a dataset (and couple future datasets). These clean datasets will be used by the Data Scientist.

Comment: Do you test your data pipeline with regular python tests? or use the pandas dataframe testing functions? Do you create a test csv (including all the possible cases the code might find) for that purpose?

Comment: I'd honestly still consider it a part of an ETL pipeline, you're just in charge of the "T" part and someone's in charge of the "E" and the "L". In my case, I'm usually handling all 3 cases haha

Comment: I see. Hey @zero, thank you for sharing your experience. Hope I find you around for future questions :)